x86 When we use fastcall, why does caller clean stack?
In fastcall functions, the callee cleans the stack and returns the value in eax. This completes the function call.And actually we put first two arguments in ecx and edx, still caller cleans stack 8 bytes.
I wonder why happens that way. We put the datas into registers not stack? Am i right?
How is it possible cleaning registers that way?
Example Code:
#include <iostream>

int __fastcall TestFunction(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4, int num5)
{
    int nSum = 0;
    nSum = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5;
    return nSum;
}

int main()
{
    int nSum = 0;
    nSum = TestFunction(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
    printf("Result: %d", nSum);
    return 0;
}



Are you asking about the add esp,8 after printf ? printf is vararg function so stack is cleaned up after printf

I got the picture from this content https://tufan-gungor.github.io/posts/x86-calling-conventions/#:~:text=We%20told%20that%20the%20callee%20is%20responsible%20for%20stack%20cleaning%20(not%20registers)%2C%20so%20in%20the%20last%20box%20you%20can%20see%20caller%20cleaning%208%20bytes
It says "We told that the callee is responsible for stack cleaning (not registers), so in the last box you can see caller cleaning 8 bytes."  I thought it was belong to fastcall cause it says so

I just glanced and from the wordings it appears that the registers are being cleaned up in stack  which is contradictory. The add esp 8 belongs to printf argument 1 format string , 2 value passed to format  the tegisters ecx and edx are not cleared by that instruction.

Thank you for your answers :)
